# How do I tell visualvm where to find my source code?

Tags: java, visualvm

I'm running VisualVM to profile a simple Java application. When I double-click on a method in the profiling pane (hoping to get more details on it), then it says "No source found for class ....". I know where the source is. How do I tell VisualVM where to look?

Comment: Just a guess, but what if you put the .java files next to the .class files on the classpath? Or if they're in a jar, bundle source and classes so they're next to each other.

Comment: I tried adding the .java files to my main .jar file alongside the .class files, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 7):

I took a stack dump of the VisualVM process while it was displaying that error dialog, and it seems that the problem lies in the class [org.netbeans.modules.profiler.api.GoToSource](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/org/netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-profiler-api/RELEASE73&path=/Source%20Packages/org.netbeans.modules.profiler.api/GoToSource.java), in the method `openSourceImpl`.

This method tries to load the source using any registered implementations of the `GoToSourceProvider` service provider interface, and displays the error message if none of them manage to display the source code in question.

*My guess is that the current, default version of VisualVM doesn't have any `GoToSourceProviders` registered, and therefore will always fail to look-up source code.*

From the package name it appears that `GoToSourceProvider` is an SPI for the profiler module, but I wasn't able to find any documentation on how to implement this SPI, and it doesn't seem to be part of the VisualVM extension points.

Comment: Sounds like this is an oversight when cutting out the profiler from Netbeans to make the stand alone VisualVM.

Answer (score 0):

Hello something virtually same like VisualVM is implemented in NetBeans IDE (I'm using 8.0.2). You just click `Profile->Project Profile`. Showing you source code upon clicking is working there. But unfortunately there is no more detailed info which lines of code takes most time.

For that I will modify code and I will count manually using

```
long beg = System.nanoTime() 
lineISuspect
sum += System.nanoTime() - beg;
```