# How can I find an anonymous inner class in Eclipse given only its synthetic name (Class$N)?

Tags: java, eclipse, visualvm, anonymous-inner-class

How do I find an anonymous inner class if I have only been given the name of the class `Class$N` when using Eclipse, without going through the code and counting each anonymous class? Is there a 'jump to anonymous class declaration' feature where I can enter the $suffix number?

The Search->Java feature was not helpful.

I am using VisualVM to find CPU hotspots. My hotspot is in an anonymous class named SomeClass$5. VisualVM cannot find the source for my class and I (and others) cannot find how to attach the source to VisualVM, shown  [here](https://www.java.net/forum/topic/java-tools/java-development-tools/attach-source-code-visualvm-profiler) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618239/how-do-i-tell-visualvm-where-to-find-my-source-code). The launcher plugin does not resolve this.

Counting the anonymous declarations is not an option because in the long-run the risk of human error sorting through hundreds of lines can result in a lot of time wasted trying to work on the wrong anonymous class just to find out it was the wrong class.

As a workaround I'm testing the classes with  `'System.out.println("this="+this.getClass().getName());'` in a method to ensure it is the right one, but there's got to be a better way.

Comment: Great question. I know two ways: Counting (which is error prone) and giving the class a name (i.e. turning an anonymous class into an inner class) which kind of ruins the benefits of the anonymous class. Plus when I think about Java 8 ... there should be a better way.

Comment: Two more ways to find the declaration: `Class.forName("SomeClass$5").getEnclosingClass/Method/Constructor()` (but may be ambiguous if there are many anonymous classes in the same scope). `javap -v SomeClass$5.class` and check the LineNumberTable attributes of the methods (but may not be present if the .class files were compiled without debug information or obfuscated).  (These don't help getting Eclipse or VisualVM to find your code automatically, and so don't answer the question as posed.)

Comment: Just info about YourKit Java Profiler: "...Take note of the extremely useful ability to locate the code of anonymous classes and their methods, which is a very difficult thing to do manually." [link]{https://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/eclipse.jsp}

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom your idea is great, why not make an answer out of it?

Comment: @BastianVoigt I felt it didn't answer the question (about using Eclipse), but they are useful workarounds.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do this in Eclipse, but I can offer two other ways to find the declaration.

---

You can call `Class.forName("SomeClass$5")`, then call one of [Class.getEnclosingMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingMethod--) or [Class.getEnclosingConstructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingConstructor--) or [Class.getEnclosingClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingClass--) to find its immediately enclosing definition.  This may be ambiguous if multiple anonymous classes are in the same enclosing member, but it gives you somewhere to start looking.

---

You can disassemble the compiled class file using the javap tool with `javap -v SomeClass$5.class`.  If the class file was compiled with debug information, and the anonymous class contained at least one method definition, the `LineNumberTable` attributes of those method definition(s) will indicate where they were defined in the source file.  The `SourceFile` attribute will contain the source file name.  The `EnclosingMethod` attribute will name the enclosing method (if there is one), and the `InnerClasses` attribute will have information about enclosing and inner classes (including unrelated classes that are merely *used*, so be careful when interpreting).