# Attaching Source to VisualVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, profiling, visualvm

Been using VisualVM for years, and it's bugged me that there is this one error I keep getting, that I've never found a solution - and would sure improve the debugging workflow tenfold.

When you double-click on a class name inside the Call Tree, I always get an error like the following:

[image: Modal dialog for "No source found for ..."]

It's really annoying. I'd love for this to just open up my editor to that file (to the right line number would be a bonus) so I could quickly get to editing / view the code context.

Does anyone know how to configure VisualVM so it can locate the source?  Integration with Eclipse get bonus points. FWIW: Just adding the source path to the classpath does not work, and unfortunately a carton of milk has better documentation than VisualVM.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618239/how-do-i-tell-visualvm-where-to-find-my-source-code